# alpha value of uitabbaritem

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, alpha

I am trying to figure out how to set my tabbaritem icon(image) to 0 so I can give it a fade animation once it loads onto the screen... but I just don't know how to do it..

this is how I am adding the images to the tabbar..

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    self.button0.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"];
    self.button1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"];
    self.button2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon3.png"];
    self.button3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon4.png"];
    self.button4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon5.png"];
    self.button5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"];


}
```

I will animate them with a method that looks something like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             // Do your animations here
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             if (finished) {
                                 // Do your method here after your animation.

                             }
                         }];
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update this is my latest attempt thats not working yet..

```
buttonImage0.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"];
    buttonImage0.alpha = 0.0;
    self.button0.image = buttonImage0.image;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{
                         // Do your animations here.
                         buttonImage0.alpha = 1.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {
                             // Do your method here after your animation.
                         }
                     }];
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can set the alpha. Assuming that it is possible, you can set the alpha to 0 inside the animations code block.

Comment: I need to set it before the code block then set the alpha to 1 in the animation (doing like an image fade) I think i have figured it out, ill create the imageview first set the alpha and then pass that image to the tabbaritem then in the code plock i will make the image fade in.

Comment: once I am done I will post the code and you guys can tell me how bad it is :)

Answer (score 0):

UIButton is a subclass of UIView.  UIView has an alpha property.

Try:

```
self.button0.alpha = 0.0;
self.button1.alpha = 0.0;
self.button2.alpha = 0.0;
self.button3.alpha = 0.0;
self.button4.alpha = 0.0;
self.button5.alpha = 0.0;
```

in your viewDidAppear;

Then put your easing function in the animateWithDuration routine using the same alpha property!

Comment: ahhh sorry bout that but this is my bad naming conventions, its a tabbaritem, so when i try your solution I get

**Property 'alpha' not found on object of type 'UITabBarItem *'**

Comment: Try using the alpha property on the UITabBar instead of each item separately.  UITabBarItem doe NOT inherit from UIView, thus it does not have the alpha property, but UITabBar does inherit from UIView.